# Menu links stopped working

Tags: css, wordpress, hyperlink

I'm running a Wordpress website with hashtag menu links, which scroll down to the appropriate section, when clicked.

However, after I updated Wordpress to 4.5.2, the links stopped working.

Any ideas? That's the URL - http://thejurist.co/bulgaria .

Thanks!

Comment: You get this in the console: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[href^=#]:not([href=#])`. Looks valid to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the theme *DynamiX* uses a wrong piece of code and WordPress was tolerating it till now. With the recent WP update to 4.5, the folks at WordPress decided to end support for that wrong syntax and throw an error.

Do this. Open `http://thejurist.co/bulgaria/wp-content/themes/DynamiX/js/nv-script.pack.js` file and find this part:

```
k("a[href^=#]:not([href=#])").
```

Replace it with:

```
k("a[href^='#']:not([href='#'])").
```

That should fix it.
You can find further details about this in the [WordPress Codex](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/read-this-first-wordpress-45-master-list?replies=7#post-8268201).

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, that selector is not working, even though the version of jQuery is latest. May be, it is because of `migrate`.

Do this. Open `http://thejurist.co/bulgaria/wp-content/themes/DynamiX/js/nv-script.pack.js?ver%5B0%5D=jquery` file and find this part:

```
k("a[href^=#]:not([href=#])").
```

Replace it with:

```
k("a[href^=#]").not("[href=#])").
```

That should fix it.

Comment: I think I did it - but it doesn't work still. By the way, I found out that the #top link is working, just the others aren't.

Comment: @nicksss Oh... Looks like the migrate is what is making it tough.